# AWS S3 object prefix redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with a bunch of objects based on the version.
For example:

Bucket:

- obj-0.3/ (created at 12.12.2021)
- obj-0.2/ (created at 11.12.2021)
- obj-0.1/ (created at 10.12.2021)

From that, I would like to have an object(prefix) called "latest" that will point to the last created object. Is it something achievable?
Example:

Bucket:

- latest/ (this object/folder has nothing but will point to obj-0.3 or any new object that will be created later)
- obj-0.3/ (created at 12.12.2021)
- obj-0.2/ (created at 11.12.2021)
- obj-0.1/ (created at 10.12.2021)

Comment: you can check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-websiteconfiguration-routingrules-redirectrule.html

Comment: @AqibJaved Checking, thanks.

Comment: It seems like we need to provide the exact name of the object.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What do you mean by "a bunch of objects based on the version"? And what do you mean by "object(prefix)"? Can you possibly edit your question to provide an example of what you are wanting to do?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I edited the question. Let me know if it still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 allows you to specify **redirection rules**, which only works **when accessing the bucket as a Static Website**.

For example, this rule redirects requests for `docs/` with `documents/`:

```json
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "docs/"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "documents/"
        }
    }
]
```

See: [Configure redirection rules to use advanced conditional redirects - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects)

Comment: I guess I won't be able to redirect requests dynamically (with the last created prefix)

Comment: Correct. You would need to edit the rules. Also, this only works when accessing objects via HTTP/S calls to the Static Website, so it might not be compatible with the way you are accessing files.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am also looking into bucket versioning but unfortunately, it also doesn't work on the prefix level. It seems to me that it only versioning an atomic object.

Comment: Yes. Objects that are 'overwritten' are saved as previous versions. It is managed at the object-level, so would not be applicable for your use-case.